# Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on array

Tags: php, yii2

У меня есть модель товаров `Products` и модель количества товаров `Amounts`. В модели `Products` есть связь

```
public function getAmounts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Amounts::className(), ['product_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Пытаюсь создать форму, поле для количества хочу записать так

```
<?=$form->field($model->amounts, 'amount')->textInput(['class' => 'form-control m-input', 'placeholder' => ''])->label(false)?>
```

И получаю ошибку

```
Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on array
```

Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 0):

`getAmounts()` Возвращает массив данных. Судя по вопросу, необходим count моделей Amounts. Только не совсем понятно, для чего это выводить в поле input? `Amounts::className()` давно пора заменить на `Amounts::class`, так быстрее работает.

**UPD**
Вероятно, код реляции может выглядеть таким образом:

```
public function getAmounts()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Amounts::className(), ['product_id' => 'id']);
}
```

А в форме надо указать конкретное поле из модели Amounts

```
<?=$form->field($model->amounts, 'fieldNameFromAmountTable')->textInput(['class' => 'form-control m-input', 'placeholder' => ''])->label(false)?>
```

Для генерации инпута нам надо в него скинуть модель и название поля. В данном случае hasOne() вернет модель. И проверку не забыть сделать, если ничего не вернет, тогда надо будет создать новую модель.

Comment: если я меняю на `hasOne()` - та же ошибка

Comment: В свойстве amount модели Products что должно быть? Или ты хочешь в инпут вставить объект? hasOne() возвращает AR, а hasMany() массив эктиврекордов.

Comment: мне нужно в форму передать связанное поле

Comment: Дополнил ответ, возможно поможет этот вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант. Создайте в модели `Products` вирутальное поле `amount`.

На форме:

```
<?=$form->field($model, 'amount')->textInput(['class' => 'form-control m-input', 'placeholder' => ''])->label(false)?>
```

В `afterSave()` сохраняйте связанную модель.

Способов много..